# Solving $\sin(t+am)=a$ where $-1 \le m \le 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What theory or algorithm would I need to research to solve equations such as $\sin(t+am)=a$ (knowing that $-1 \le m \le 1$) for the value of $a$?

My equations may become more complex but have similar properties (and always the constraint on the range of the $m$ variables), such as $\sin(t+\sin(th+am_1)m_2)=a$.

I've played with Wolfram Alpha enough to verify that these functions stay monotonic with $t$ but still can't figure out how to solve them analytically in the real domain.

EDIT: Here is a piece of music using almost exclusively equations like this to directly calculate the time domain audio samples: http://soundcloud.com/full-synthetic/sunshine It's not the greatest but every synth is on that form.

Comment: Numerical methods (e.g., Newton's method). You're not going to find a "nice" solution at all. Others may be able to explain just why that is.

Comment: Yeah, I know just barely enough to recognize that as a "not going to happen", but I don't actually know why. Hopefully someone else will come along and explain.

Comment: May I ask where you encountered this problem?

Comment: My software synthesizer :) I want to do away with oversampling, but still allow for oscillators to be routed into their own phase (currently I use something like a recurrence relation at the effective sample rate to approximate these, but with complex patches, the oversampling required becomes massive)

Comment: That doesn't really mean anything to me, but it sounds noble. I bet you can find a really efficient way to approximate this numerically that will work perfectly in your application. You may want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll probably be back after I get it prototyped, I predict newtons method might be a bit expensive when it needs to happen to every sample in an audio stream :P

Comment: Are your $t$ and $m$ fixed?

Comment: Newton's method may not be the best (I haven't a clue) but don't knock it till you've tried it. If you start with a good approximation (table lookup if possible, or linear approximation) and you calculate the sines and cosines with increasing precision at each step rather than calculating them to full precision each time, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Sometimes m is fixed, other times it can be described in terms of t (although, that description can sometimes leak more trig in so I just treat it as an arbitrary real number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bisection technique is also viable, and offers a large benefit over newton's iteration: It guarantees a solution.

Comment: :D this solves the exact issues I was having getting NaN results sometimes.

Comment: To be fair, newton should be a bit faster, maybe it's better as a fallback solution?

Answer (score 2):

This does not really answer the question, but it's too big for a comment. Using Newton's method to solve $\sin(t+ma) - a = 0$:

Let $f(x)=\sin(t+ma)-a$, so $f'(x)=m\cos(t+ma)$. Then
$$x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac {\sin(t+mx_n)-x_n}{m\cos(t+mx_n)}=x_n - \frac 1 m \tan(t+mx_n)+\frac{x_n}{m}\sec(t+mx_n)$$

Using WolframAlpha to get [a series expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+of+x%2B1%2Fm%2a%28x%2asec%28t%2Bmx%29+-+tan+%28t%2Bmx%29%29),
\begin{multline}
x_{n+1} = 
-\frac{\tan t}m+\left(\frac{\sec t}m-\tan^2 t\right)x_n
+\tan t \sec^2 t(\cos t - m)x_n^2 \\
+\frac 1 {24} m \sec^4 t (8m \cos (2t)-16m+15\cos t - 3\cos 3t)x_n^3
+\cdots.
\end{multline}
This looks pretty nasty, but if $t$ and $m$ are fixed (not clear from the problem), you can precompute all the coefficients of $x_n^k$, making each step of Newton's method reasonably efficient. If you start out with a decent initial guess (table lookup, if possible), use just a few terms of the expansion for the first step, and add terms as you proceed, it should probably be fast enough. That said, there may well be a more efficient approach to this particular problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'll upvote this when I get to 15 rep :P

Comment: also for your reference, in x86 programming, the $x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{\sin(t+mx_n)-x_n}{m\cos(t+mx_n)}$ form should be significantly simpler in machine language due to the fused sincos instruction.

Comment: @user114148, that `sincos` instruction is not necessarily going to be the fastest way--it's one instruction, but it's really firmware rather than hardware. You may want to take a look at [this SSE and SSE2 optimized version](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/), which I would expect could make things go real fast if you use them right. That said, you can almost certainly do better.